# O que são Progressive Web Apps?

Tags: aplicação-web, pwa, progressive-web-apps

Olá, já li referências por ai, e para complementar nossa comunidade, seguem as dúvidas.

- O que é exatamente Progressive Web App (PWA) ou Aplicação Web
  Progressiva?
- Que vantagens existem em comparação aos aplicativos nativos e ou híbridos?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Progressive Web Apps são experiências que combinam o melhor da Web e o
>   melhor dos aplicativos. Eles são úteis para os usuários desde a
>   primeira visita em uma guia de navegador sem exigir instalações.
>   Conforme o usuário desenvolve uma relação com o aplicativo ao longo do
>   tempo, ele se torna cada vez mais eficaz. Ele é carregado com rapidez,
>   mesmo em redes instáveis, envia notificações push relevantes, tem um
>   ícone na tela inicial e é carregado como uma experiência de tela
>   inteira de alto nível.
>
> O que é um Progressive Web App?
>
> Um Progressive Web App é:
>
> - **Progressivo** - Funciona para qualquer usuário, independentemente do    navegador escolhido, pois é criado com aprimoramento progressivo
>     como    princípio fundamental.
> - **Responsivo** - Se adequa a qualquer formato: desktop, celular, tablet    ou o que for inventado a seguir.
> - **Independente de conectividade** - Aprimorado com service workers para    trabalhar off-line ou em redes de baixa qualidade.
> - **Semelhante a aplicativos** - Parece com aplicativos para os usuários,    com interações e navegação de estilo de aplicativos, pois
>     é compilado    no modelo de shell de aplicativo.
> - **Atual** - Sempre atualizado graças ao processo de atualização do    service worker.
> - **Seguro** - Fornecido via HTTPS para evitar invasões e garantir que o    conteúdo não seja adulterado.
> - **Descobrível** - Pode ser identificado como "aplicativo" graças aos    manifestos W3C e ao escopo de registro do service worker, que
>     permitem que os mecanismos de pesquisa os encontrem.
> - **Reenvolvente** - Facilita o reengajamento com recursos como    notificações push.
> - **Instalável** - Permite que os usuários "guardem" os aplicativos mais    úteis em suas telas iniciais sem precisar acessar uma loja de 
>     aplicativos.
> - **Linkável** - Compartilhe facilmente por URL, não requer instalação    complexa.
>
> *Referência*: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/

**Que vantagens existem em comparação aos aplicativos nativos e ou híbridos?**

Acredito que a vantagem na escolha de desenvolver um PWA é ele ser acessível em multiplataformas (Android, iOS, etc) além de que também será acessível em multidispositivos (smartphones, tablets e desktops). Os pontos negativos é que atualmente algumas features são impossíveis de serem implementadas pois o PWA não tem acesso a componentes como Bluetooth, NFC, Fingerprint etc.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Recomendo também a leitura de um artigo do tableless: https://medium.com/tableless/introdu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-aos-progressive-web-apps-ad47ba24cddb#.58g85rpyw

Answer (score 8):

As grandes empresas e entusiastas de tecnologia já percebem que o [número de downloads de aplicativos para celular vem diminuindo a cada ano](http://www.androidauthority.com/end-era-app-downloads-decline-usa-698555/) e diante desta situação surgiram os progressive web apps. Os **Progressive Web Apps** são um conjunto de técnicas para desenvolver aplicações web, adicionando funcionalidades que antes só eram possíveis em apps nativos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As seguintes características, [criadas pelo Google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/), definem o que são esperados de um Progressive Web App:

- **Progressivo**: para qualquer usuário, independente do browser
- **Responsivo**: feito para qualquer dispositivo: desktop, tablet e mobile
- **Conexão**: funciona mesmo se o usuário estiver offline
- **App-like**: o usuário se sente em um aplicativo nativo
- **Atualizado**: não é necessário baixar atualizações do aplicativo, o browser simplesmente irá detectar e atualizar automaticamente, caso necessário.
- **Seguro**: somente com https
- **Engajável**: através de push notifications, o usuário pode ser constantemente engajado.
- **Instalável**: é possível adicionar um ícone na tela principal do smartphone com apenas um clique.

Se antes somente os aplicativos nativos tinham: push notifications, funcionamento offline, geolocalização e ícone na home screen, com os progressive web apps podemos ter estas funcionalidades na web.

Alguns benefícios que podem ser citados em relação aos PWAs:

- **Retenção**: Um usuário que deseja experimentar um aplicativo, precisa passar por diversas etapas como buscar o aplicativo, instalar, abrir, liberar permissões do celular, etc. Quando falamos de Progressive Web Apps, o usuário basta acessar o link e já está usando o aplicativo. Ou seja, o usuário não precisa se comprometer, e perder tempo, em instalar um app para só depois poder avaliar se esse aplicativo valeu a pena ou não.
- **Economia**: Se você realmente precisa de um aplicativo nativo, os gastos necessários para contratar uma equipe especializada de desenvolvedores iOS/Android certamente serão bem investidos.Mas se não é necessário um aplicativo nativo no seu caso, um PWA talvez atenda muito bem os seus requisitos de negócio. Se esse for o caso, a economia gerada por essa decisão será imensa.

Algumas desvantagens que podem ser citadas em relação aos PWAs:

- **Limitação:** Um Progressive Web App não consegue reproduzir atualmente todas as funcionalidades que um aplicativo nativo pode produzir, exemplo: bluetooth, lista de contatos e NFC, são alguns exemplos de features que não conseguem ser acessadas pelos Progressive Web Apps.

Fontes - Conteúdo adaptado dos sites:

- [Introdução aos Progressive Web Apps](https://medium.com/tableless/introdu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-aos-progressive-web-apps-ad47ba24cddb#.t4d40achp)
- [Seu primeiro Progressive Web App](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/)

Answer (score 7):

**O que é exatamente Progressive Web App (PWA) ou Aplicação Web Progressiva?**

Essa parte você encontra na [documentação](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/):

> **Apps progressivos para a Web**
>
> São experiências que combinam o melhor da Web e o melhor dos apps.
>   Eles são úteis para os usuários desde o primeiro acesso a uma guia do
>   navegador, sem necessidade de instalação. Conforme o usuário constrói
>   uma relação com o app ao longo do tempo, ele se torna cada vez mais
>   poderoso. Ele carrega rapidamente, mesmo em redes instáveis, envia
>   notificações push relevantes, tem um ícone da tela inicial e é
>   carregado como uma experiência de tela cheia de alto nível.
>
> **Vantagens Técnicas**
>
> - *Progressivos*: funcionam para todos os usuários, independentemente da escolha de navegador, pois são criados com aprimoramento
>     progressivo como princípio central;
> - *Responsivos*: ajustam-se a qualquer formato: computador, dispositivo móvel, tablet ou o que quer que esteja por vir;
> - *Independentes de conectividade*: aprimorados para usar `service workers` para funcionar offline ou em redes de baixa qualidade;
> - *Semelhantes a um app*: o usuário sente que está usando um app, com interações e navegação no mesmo estilo de apps, pois eles são criados
>     no modelo app shell;
> - *Atualizados*: sempre atualizados, graças ao processo de atualização do *service worker*;
> - *Seguros*: veiculados por `HTTPS` para impedir o rastreamento e assegurar que o conteúdo não foi adulterado;
> - *Detectáveis*: são identificáveis como "aplicativos" graças ao escopo de registro do *service worker* e manifestos W3C, permitindo
>     que mecanismos de pesquisa os encontrem;
> - *Reengajáveis*: facilitam o reengajamento por meio de recursos como notificações `push`;
> - *Instaláveis*: permitem que os usuários "salvem" os apps que consideram mais úteis na sua tela inicial sem a inconveniência de ter
>     que usar uma loja de apps;
> - *Vinculáveis por link*: compartilhamento fácil por meio de URL, sem a exigência de instalações complexas.

**Que vantagens existem em comparação aos aplicativos nativos e ou híbridos?**

Para podermos utilizar um aplicativo é preciso baixá-lo. O que as PWA trazem como grande vantagem é que o usuário não precisa baixar o aplicativo, isso porque, elas rodam diretamente no browser.

As PWA "são diferentes de um app híbrido, que utiliza uma aplicação em HTML5 envolvida por um casco nativo, mas que ainda assim precisa ser instalado pela App Store". ([fonte](https://brasil.uxdesign.cc/o-que-s%C3%A3o-progressive-web-apps-86e1b5306051#.cg6jb1exr)).

Outra grande vantagem das PWA que você precisa saber basicamente HTML, CSS, JavaScript e Chrome DevTools.

Referências:

- [Progressive Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/)
- [Getting Start](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/your-first-progressive-web-app/)
- [O que são PWA](http://arquiteturadeinformacao.com/mobile/o-que-sao-progressive-web-apps/)

Answer (score 5):

PWA são features de experiência que uma aplicação web pode fornecer para o usuário de modo que seja similar a de uma aplicação nativa.

O fato da aplicação ser Progressiva é que a a medida que o usuário está usando a aplicação como Web, ela vai cada vez mais se integrando ao dispositivo, assumindo uma forma mais nativa, por assim dizer.

Entre essas features, existem:

- Push Notification;
- Usabilidade offline;
- Acesso a serviços mobile que uma aplicação nativa tem (câmera, geolocation, vibrações, etc);
- Acesso a aplicação pela homescreen do dispositivo.

A principal vantagem é a usabilidade; Por exemplo: um usuário pode não desejar baixar a aplicação na App Store só para usar em um caso específico ou em algumas outras poucas vezes. Nesse caso a aplicação se torna híbrida em questões de uso, por assim dizer; ela vai poder ter uso tanto pelo launcher do navegador quanto de um ícone na home do dispositivo.

Além disso, a performace também é notável, pois a aplicação roda no browser do dispositivo sem precisar de qualquer tweaking (como as aplicações híbridas e os Cordova da vida) para poder rodar como nativa e, através de ServiceWorkers (feature que uma PWA possui) o usuário pode ter os dados da aplicação em cache e ter sua navegação tão (ou mais) performática que uma aplicação nativa.

Recomendo ouvir este Podcast para saber mais sobre: http://hipsters.tech/progressive-web-apps-hipsters-03/