# Qual é a diferença entre "Instant Apps" e "Progressive Web Apps" (PWA)

Tags: pwa, progressive-web-apps, instant-app

Tenho ouvido falar bastante sobre  **Instant Apps** e **Progressive Web Apps** (PWA). Vi que eles têm algumas coisa em comum, mas como sou leigo na área fiquei com algumas  dúvidas.

- Quais seriam de fato as vantagens de um sobe o outro (prós e contras / Android x iOS)?
- Qual deles é mais seguro e tem o desempenho melhor?
- A longo prazo um vai prevalecer e o outro pode vir a morrer, um pode substituir o outro?

Comment: Relacionado: [O que são Progressive Web Apps?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153860/28595)