# Que tecnologias posso usar para criar um PWA

Tags: aplicação-web, pwa

Já vi [O que são Progressive Web Apps?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/153860/) e a documentação da google, mas ainda estou com um dúvida:

Quais são as tecnologias disponíveis que podem ser usadas para criar uma aplicação web progressiva?

Além, claro de HTML, CSS e JS. Por exemplo, posso usar PHP para criar uma PWA? acredito que não já que, posteriormente, a aplicação será rodada em um celular sem um servidor local, sendo assim essa aplicação precisaria de acesso a internet (indo contra um dos princípios do PWA, funcionar offline)

Comment: Você pode recuperar os valores de um back-end PHP e depois salvar num localStorage, não vejo impeditivo nisso.

Comment: @Laerte pode criar uma resposta com um exemplo simples de uso do PHP como PWA?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam basicamente teria a parte da _view_ da aplicação feita em JS que consumiria um serviço em PHP. Sempre que estivesse ligado à internet iria a esse serviço e fazia uma cópia para armazenamento local para que quando não tivesse ligação à internet pudesse pelo menos apresentar a informação mais recente que tem disponível.

Comment: Isso ! Os frameworks, angular, Vuejs e a biblioteca reactjs, já fazem isso.

Comment: A pergunta já responde: CSS, JS e HTML. Nada mais. De nada adianta falar em framework, pois continua sendo feito em CSS, JS e HTML (o próprio framework vai acabar dependendo destas 3 tecnologias). O que vai mudar é a parte server side, para atualizar a aplicação quando ela sair do offline. Aí pode usar o que quiser, desde que o PWA use o mesmo protocolo..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para criar um PWA, basicamente você precisa de HTML, JavaScript e CSS.

Em linhas gerais, PWA é um Web App com um [Service Worker](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/?hl=pt-br) implementado permitindo que você torne sua aplicação offline e consiga mandar push notification.

O que torna seu site um PWA são esses conceitos: [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/153860/o-que-s%C3%A3o-progressive-web-apps/190205#190205).

Para acelerar o desenvolvimento da sua aplicação pode-se utilizar frameworks como: AngularJS, React etc. Não é obrigatório, só irá facilitar.

Para o backend é só utilizar Web Service RESTful. A tecnologia pode ser qualquer uma!

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que depois que você ter um background satisfatório em relação ao javascript, você poderia focar em um framework para agilizar o desenvovlimento de um PWA.

Minha opinião é usar VueJs pela facilidade e curva de aprendizado baixa, é meu framework of choice, digamos assim haha.

Outra dica, outro framework que eu uso, é o Quasar Framework. Para mim é o melhor e mais bem documentada ferramenta. Muito intuítvo e fácil de aprender com os exemplos, ótima comunidade no discord.

Depois de ter uma noção com o VueJS e seus plugins como: vue-router, vue-cli, vueX sem dúvida você pode criar um ótimo PWA.

No quesito de armazenamento offline, você poderia usar uma lib chamada [localForage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage) para isso e depois que obtiver a conexão com a internet, sincroniza-la com o banco de sua preferência, sendo real-time (mongo, firebase) ou não.

Vou deixar os links para que você de uma olhada e ficar por dentro do Vue e o Quasar.

[Vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/en/) Criar rotas para as páginas web.

[Curso que eu comprei para aprofundar o conhecimento em vueJs e plugins](https://vueschool.io/)

Obs: É em ingles, mas você pode mandar um e-mail e negociar um valor bem abaixo do que eles pedem, são muito solicitos e me ajudaram nesse quesito.

[Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html) é state management, muito bom para quando a aplicação começa a crescer e ajuda na escalabilidade, organizando melhor os componentes e as interações entre eles.

[Quasar Framework](http://quasar-framework.org/)

Se você realmente optar por usar o vueJs e quasar, fica aqui o [link](https://discord.gg/bCa2XXd) do discord para possíveis dúvidas, falando diretamente com a comunidade e seus desenvolvedores.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar por exemplo o [ionic](http://ionic.io) para criar o seu PWA e utilizar qualquer linguagem de programação WEB para criar uma API Rest no back-end. 
Com o Angular você poderá fazer integração com recursos nativos do celular e salvar os dados offline e caso necessário sincronizar com o seu backend quando tiver conexão.