# Existe a possibilidade de transformar uma aplicação construída com PHP em PWA?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pwa

Tenho uma aplicação construída com o Code Igniter e desejo transformá-lo em um Progressive Web App, Quais arquivos eu deveria armazenar em cache? Qual seria a melhor estratégia?

Answer (score 1):

Não, isto não faz sentido. [PWA](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153860/101) é uma aplicação de *frontend*, e PHP é usado no *backend*. Por outro lado, qualquer PWA feito corretamente se comunica com qualquer *backend*.